# Android L is ignoring shapes as drawable background

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm testing Android L Preview on my Nexus 5. I've got problem with my app.

I've got some TextViews with background set:

```
android:background="@drawable/rounded_textview"
```

And "rounded_textview" is just shape. It is working great below <=API19.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="3dp">
<solid android:color="#999999"/>
<corners
 android:bottomRightRadius="2dp"
 android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
 android:topLeftRadius="2dp"
 android:topRightRadius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

On Android L Developer Preview background is ignored. All my TextViews are transparent. 
Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This bug has been reported on the Android Developer Preview bug tracker and will hopefully be fixed before the final Release of Android L:
https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=177

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I found that wrapping the shape in a selector and item tag made it work

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="@color/gray" />

            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
                android:topRightRadius="3dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you for the workaround, however I still hope Google will fix this before Android L official release. Has anyone reported this on the official Android bug tracker yet ?

Comment: This worked for a solid colored shape :) however wrapping in a selector had no effect on a shape that is gradient :/

Comment: If you have the same radius on all corners, you can simply use android:radius="3dp". It works on Android L.

Comment: Apparently, this has been fixed in the Nexus 5 Developer images that were updated today!

Answer (score 0):

Just use android:radius, not use each corner options.
I had a same problem, but I was able to solve the problem using this way.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="3dp">
<solid android:color="#999999"/>
  <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Yes. But it was just example. I want to use different radius for each corners. But the answer below is working in my case. Put your stuff in <selector>.