# Button's background drawable (shape) won't show up unless app API is 20+ (Android L)

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-5.0-lollipop, android-shape

In my Android app, I'm trying to set a simple ring shape as background drawable for my Buttons. But as much as I try, the XML preview ignores the background drawable **unless the API level is set to 20 (Android L)**

What's going on? I'm sure people used to set shapes for buttons before L.

Code for my XML shape for `button_ring.xml` located in /drawables folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring" >
    <solid android:color="#4CD964" />
</shape>
```

and code for my button defined in layout folder

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/five"
    android:tag="@string/five"
    style="@style/CustomButton"
    android:background="@drawable/button_ring" />
```

My Gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
}
```

and finally a video to see what I mean: [Video](http://cld.persiangig.com/dl/FwXKi/CsS3iQJozX/shape%20problem.mov)

Comment: Android-L is not sdk=20.

Comment: shape drawable is not working android l preview

Comment: This solved it for me with a TextView:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441422/android-l-is-ignoring-shapes-as-drawable-background